# Map Existing MongoDB Database With Doctrine2 ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a project which is created in Java with Mongo DB as the backend. I am trying to create a Symfony2 project to connect to the same existing Mongo database. In Doctrine2 ORM we can easily create entity classes with an existing SQL database. I am using MongoDB for the first time and need to integrate this existing database with the new app using Doctrine2 ODM. How can we generate ODM classes from that existing MongoDB database or integrate it any other way.

Thanks :)

Comment: This sounds like something that should be covered by the documentation.  For example, [this page](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/console-commands.html) talks about code generation.